# git format-patch disable patch number in subject line

Tags: git, numbers, patch, format-patch

When I use `git format-patch` to create multiple patch files at once, the number of the patch is added to the subject line.

```
Subject: [PATCH <number>/<amount>] <msg>
```

Is it possible to disable `<number>/<amount>`?

Comment: Per [the documentation](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-format-patch.html), `-N` or `--no-numbered`

Comment: It worked. Thank you. For some reason I missed this option. If you write an answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's the default action if there are multiple patch files.  To avoid numbering patch subjects ever, use `-N` or `--no-numbered`.  To force numbering even if there is only one patch, use `-n` or `--numbered`.  The `--numbered` / `--no-numbered` spelling pair mirrors other Git commands with boolean options, and other options in `git format-patch` itself, such as `--[no-]cover-letter`, `--no-thread` vs `--thread[=<style>]`, and so on.

For more details, see [the documentation](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-format-patch.html).